# How can I replace a string match with part of itself in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, text, python-re

I need to process text in Python and replace any occurrence of `"[xz]"` by `"x"`, where `"x"` is the first letter enclosed in the brackets, and `"z"` can be a string of variable length. Note that I do not want the brackets in the output.

For example, `"alEhos[cr@e]sjt"` should become `"alEhoscsjt"`

I think `re.sub()` could be a way to go, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly using the `re.sub()` method, you can use the [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) method to find all substrings *(in a non-greedy fashion)* that begins and ends with the proper square brackets.

Then, iterate through the matches and use the `str.replace()` method to replace each match in the string with the second character in the match:

```
import re

s = "alEhos[cr@e]sjt"

for m in re.findall("\[.*?\]", s):
    s = s.replace(m, m[1])

print(s)
```

Output:

```
alEhoscsjt
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work for the example given.

```
import re

example = "alEhos[cr@e]sjt"
result = re.sub(r'(.*)\[(.).*\](.*)', r'\1\2\3', example)
print(result)
```

The regular expression uses three capturing groups. `\1` and `\3` capture the text before and after the square brackets. `\2` captures the first character inside the bracket.

Output:

```
alEhoscsjt
```

If you have more than one occurrence of square brackets in your string, you can use the following:

```
example = "alEhos[cr@e]sjt[abc]xyz"
result = re.sub(r'\[(.).*?\]', r'\1', example)
print(result)
```

This version replaces all of the bracketed substrings (including brackets) by the first character found inside the brackets. (Note the use of the non-greedy qualifier to avoid consuming everything between the first `[` and last `]`.)

Output:

```
alEhoscsjtaxyz
```

Comment: This does not work when there are multiple occurrences of a substring enclosed in square brackets in the string.

Comment: @AnnZen Without an example showing what the output should be for that case, we don't know what "does not work" means.

Comment: The OP specified *"and replace **any** occurrence of `"[xz]"` by `"x"`"*.

Comment: @AnnZen Ok, I can go along with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `split()` method:

```
str1 = "alEhos[cr@e]sjt"

lst1 = str1.split("[")
lst2 = lst1[1].split("]")

print(lst1[0]+lst2[0][0]+lst2[1])
```

Comment: This does not work when there are multiple occurrences of a substring enclosed in square brackets in the string.